# SQL server date convert giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select A.ACCOUNT_NUM,
       convert(date, B.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 112) as 'EFFECTIVE_DATE',
       B.INTEREST_RATE
from Table1 A
left join Table2 B
on A.ACCOUNT_NUM = B.ACCOUNT_NUM
```

ACCOUNT_NUM is varchar(12) in both tables, EFFECTIVE_DATE is varchar(8) and in the format '20131018'
This is giving me a 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time string'. If I run the query without the convert it runs fine.

However I've checked the contents of EFFECTIVE_DATE using ISDATE() and there are no issues there. 
Also, if I do the following:

```
select A.ACCOUNT_NUM,
       B.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
       B.INTEREST_RATE
into #temp
from Table1 A
left join Table2 B
on A.ACCOUNT_NUM = B.ACCOUNT_NUM


select convert(date, EFFECTIVE_DATE, 112)
from #temp
```

it correctly converts the column into date format with no errors. 
What am I missing please, it's driving me crazy and I'm sure it's something very simple!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sort of problems can happen when you store `DATE` *in* `STRING type fields`. There may be one or two strings which are *NOT convertible as date* in your column. Try this with `CASE` and see if you get the data.

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUM,
       CASE WHEN ISDATE(B.EFFECTIVE_DATE) THEN CONVERT(DATE, B.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 112) 
            ELSE CONVERT(DATE, '20000101', 112) END AS 'EFFECTIVE_DATE',
       B.INTEREST_RATE
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.ACCOUNT_NUM = B.ACCOUNT_NUM
```

If you get any `EFFECTIVE_DATE` values as `2000-01-01`, that means you have to sort out those string values.

Also, you can try below query to find out which rows are causing the issue:

```
SELECT B.ACCOUNT_NUM, B.EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM Table2 B
WHERE ISDATE(B.EFFECTIVE_DATE) = 0
```

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions and no anomalies were identified.

Comment: Nope all the dates returned were from this year as expected

Comment: It is difficult to say without looking at the exact picture.

Comment: My bad, I think it was just me being a noob. I had only checked the validity of the date strings in the 600 odd rows returned by the join. If I add `where isdate(B.EFFECTIVE_DATE)=1` onto the query it works fine. The convert is obviously performed prior to the join?

Comment: Filter applies first and that is why it works when you add WHERE clause. Have a look at the execution plan and read from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated your schema and ran your query and it worked fine. Without doubt the issue is a badly formatted string in your `Table2.EFFECTIVE_DATE` column.

Comment: Would a badly formatted string in the EFFECTIVE_DATE column not also give an error in the second code block I posted though? Because the second one works fine

Comment: No because no conversion is taking place, it's copying the VARCHAR value into a new VARCHAR column in the temp table.

Comment: Sorry I meant if I then also run the select convert from #temp it works fine

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your dataset somewhere?